# How to debug multiple level spark sql?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to scala, I tried to explode the test_tracking and test_segment but still saw the error. Anyone knows how to debug this query? Thanks a lot!

```
An error was encountered:
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`test_segment`' given input columns: [test_tracking, customer_id]; line 1 pos 8;
'Project [customer_id#42, 'explode('test_segment) AS test_segment#94]
+- Project [customer_id#42, test_tracking#91]
```

```
val list = List(3,4);
var testdata = data.selectExpr("id","explode(test_tracking) as test_tracking")
                   .selectExpr("id","explode(test_segment) as test_segment")
                   .select("id", "test_tracking.gcor_id","test_tracking.propensity","test_segment.test_ops")
                   .withColumn("new_propensity", when($"propensity" > 2.0, 2.0).when($"propensity" < 1.0, 1.0).otherwise($"propensity"))
                   .filter($"test_ops".isin(list: _*))
                   .filter($"preference" >= 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
   .select("id", "test_tracking.gcor_id","test_tracking.propensity","test_segment.test_ops")
```

You are selecting test_segment.test_ops and not test_segment

It should be clled like this:

```
.select(col("id"), col("test_tracking.gcor_id"),col("test_tracking.propensity"),col("test_segment.test_ops").as("test_segment"))
```